How does a heavy build work?
The first time I started the game I picked Wretch. I knew nothing about the game. I quickly started collecting the heaviest equipment available, thinking it must be best. I started grinding the Godrick Knight in Gatefront Ruins. I got a Partisan, later upgraded to Golden Halberd. I got the whole Godrick Knight set and a Gilded Greatshield.
The end result was that I could not roll nor parry. And I could not defeat: Crucible Knight in Limgrave Evergaol, Agheel nor the Runebear disguised as a wandering noble.
The Crucible Knight in particular just kept attacking. I could block his attack with my shield, but invariably I was eventually running out of stamina, then my guard was getting broken and I was getting killed.
I ragequit and restarted the game as an Astrologer. I managed to win (ie defeat Elden Beast and get an ending).
I think I now understand two approaches to the game: ranged INT magic and a lightweight melee build that lets me avoid enemy attacks by rolling and parrying (eg with a Buckler). But I still have no idea how to roll a heavy build.
I am restricted to melee and I cannot roll nor parry: how do I play?
How do I fight a Crucible Knight without parrying?
How do I fight large bosses with devastating unparryable attacks if I cannot roll?
Such a build should work by letting me just facetank all attacks with my heavy armor & shield, but how? It doesn't seem to work for me.

If you beat Elden Beast, I suspect you found this out eventually, but the dragon and crucible knight are significantly more dangerous than anything else in the early area. It's perfectly normal to not be able to fight them. With specific regards to parrying, that has nothing to do with weight class and everything to do with your shield. You can wear heavy armor and use a buckler and still parry.

The trick to a heavy build is to manage your equip load.
Ideally, you should try to remain below 70% (aka "Heavy Load"). At 70% equip load or above, you take twice as long to recover from a roll (a little over half a second vs. a little over a quarter second), have about 33 ms less invulnerability and a 20% slower stamina regeneration.
While a heavy load is still manageable, you should absolutely avoid reaching 100% or above (aka "Overloaded") at all costs (unless you enjoy the challenge)! When overloaded, you can no longer roll or backstep, and your movement speed is greatly reduced. This puts you at an extreme disadvantage in combat.
To reduce your equip load, you need to either use lighter equipment, or increase your maximum equip load:

Invest in Endurance. Note that your maximum equip load increases the most up until 60 Endurance.

Equip Arsenal Charm, Arsenal Charm +1, or Great-Jar's Arsenal. It weighs only 1.5 and increases your maximum equip load by 15%, 17% (+1), or 19% (Great-Jar's Arsenal). Great-Jar's Arsenal does not stack with Arsenal Charm.

Equip Erdtree's Favor, Erdtree's Favor +1, or Erdtree's Favor +2. It weighs only 1.5 and increases your maximum equip load by 5%, 6.5% (+1), or 8% (+2).



You also mention being unable to parry. Parrying is unrelated to your build weight.
To parry, you either need a shield or weapon with the parry skill, or you need to equip a corresponding Ash of War, such as Ash of War: Parry, on a shield or weapon that supports it.

hmm, i thought that in general heavy shields can't parry, only lighter shields can parry
